# Elasticsearch: sorting some items by a field where a condition is matched, others by another

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

Let's say I have an document mapped like this:

```
{
  "corp" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "staff" : {
        "properties" : {
          "created" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "public" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "salary" : {
            "type" : "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And a dataset like this:

```
[{"name": "John", "salary": 100000, "public": true, "created": "<datestamp>"},
 {"name": "Bob", "salary": 80000, "public": false, "created": "<datestamp>"},
 {"name": "Wendy", "salary": 110000, "public": true, "created": "<datestamp>"},
 {"name": "Joan", "salary": 210000, "public": false, "created": "<datestamp>"}]
```

I want to construct a sort such that we sort by salary *only* where `public=true`, then sort the rest of the items by the `created` field. The final result should be:

1. Wendy
2. John
3. Bob (depending on `created` date)
4. Joan (depending on `created` date)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
GET /corp/staff/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "public": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "salary": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "created": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```